# How to read mail through send grid using c#

Tags: c#, email, serialization, sendgrid

I have to read mails which is send by send grid through c# code.

I have read the stream which is like that

```
     --xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="headers"

Received: by 127.0.0.1 with SMTP id 8KwcWqETbu Fri, 25 Jan 2013 03:49:42 -0600 (CST)
Received: from mail-ve0-f173.google.com (mail-ve0-f173.google.com [209.85.128.173]) by mx5.sendgrid.net (Postfix) with ESMTPS id A1D5A2621B68 for <pk@replydev.socialboards.com>; Fri, 25 Jan 2013 03:49:42 -0600 (CST)
Received: by mail-ve0-f173.google.com with SMTP id b10so69883vea.32 for <pk@replydev.socialboards.com>; Fri, 25 Jan 2013 01:49:42 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=20120113; h=mime-version:x-received:date:message-id:subject:from:to :content-type:x-gm-message-state; bh=w5qN+xkC2AsH6lrtfF/wYnPJ3C3PTO0oVvChHKiLsXM=; b=hgrflJqveG6cOlK5XNz7qI3fJjIOvOeJsmZhyPU+vRFsKlLPctb91oGxz/0v+kzABj us04rC6cW6CWIIR4W1dYfUEpXYdBgbVoOMPs4ef005jMHPOfpMx81YAW6tpq1HQyLh1W 4n49LBm1GssCJhbhwSMUKRwIVqBmLtxMzVPnWVrCqMB8e2KSn78yw58JFOtf7qv+tKE3 oqa4n04ywmcVCKhEx2bhIvpo7IJQ5BjC62Q3iNdQgTJLw1eKQ9nMF8BTxXLFlFZK5HHb fpLFkgiIGqqYJioKtyS0slkJQA1P8OSrjkDnlmLXJU7btatnxd+a94wYKNB6yHwYpL+M f4SQ==
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.52.179.136 with SMTP id dg8mr4231328vdc.81.1359107382079; Fri, 25 Jan 2013 01:49:42 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.58.155.42 with HTTP; Fri, 25 Jan 2013 01:49:42 -0800 (PST)
Date: Fri, 25 Jan 2013 15:19:42 +0530
Message-ID: <CAJfhHSq2qTRHK_0_6jWQyTd9ecB61SJYDyy8mM7G3-atUN13qA@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: dfdsfdsfds
From: Pragati Kumar <pragati.kumar@sdplabs.com>
To: Eric Test <pk@replydev.socialboards.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=bcaec5014c15b870c904d419d845
X-Gm-Message-State: ALoCoQmTr/zLwW3mbRCZRyL5EOYaPnPrpXB+GEtN+sTQ1PdGB/ulN//n2SaQiYaSbKRyVaqLJfBq

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dkim"

none
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to"

Eric Test <pk@replydev.socialboards.com>
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="html"

<div dir="ltr"><br clear="all"><div style>fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfds</div>-- <br><div dir="ltr"><div>Thanks With Regards.</div><div><br></div><div><b>Pragati Kumar Singh</b></div><div><b>Software Developer (.NET)</b></div><div><b>Mob:  +91 902-363-6285</b></div>
<div><b><br></b></div><div><b>SDPLabs</b></div><div><b><a href="mailto:pragati.kumar@sdplabs.com" target="_blank">pragati.kumar@sdplabs.com</a></b></div><div><b><a href="http://www.sdplabs.com" target="_blank">www.sdplabs.com</a></b></div>
<div><br></div><div>India:  +91 0172 401 0125 (Office)</div><div>           +91 0172 465 0337 (Office)</div><div>USA:   +1 646-462-4634 (Office)</div><div>           +1 646-789-5302 (Cell)</div><div>Fax:   +1 928-563-1783</div>
</div>
</div>

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="from"

Pragati Kumar <pragati.kumar@sdplabs.com>
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfds
-- 
Thanks With Regards.

*Pragati Kumar Singh*
*Software Developer (.NET)*
*Mob:  +91 902-363-6285*
*
*
*SDPLabs*
*pragati.kumar@sdplabs.com*
*www.sdplabs.com*

India:  +91 0172 401 0125 (Office)
           +91 0172 465 0337 (Office)
USA:   +1 646-462-4634 (Office)
           +1 646-789-5302 (Cell)
Fax:   +1 928-563-1783

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="spam_report"

Spam detection software, running on the system "mx5.sendgrid.net", has
identified this incoming email as possible spam.  The original message
has been attached to this so you can view it (if it isn't spam) or label
similar future email.  If you have any questions, see
the administrator of that system for details.

Content preview:  fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfds -- Thanks With Regards. *Pragati Kumar
  Singh* *Software Developer (.NET)* *Mob:  +91 902-363-6285* * * *SDPLabs* *pragati.kumar@sdplabs.com*
   *www.sdplabs.com* India:  +91 0172 401 0125 (Office)  +91 0172 465 0337 (Office)
   USA:  +1 646-462-4634 (Office)  +1 646-789-5302 (Cell) Fax: +1 928-563-1783
   [...] 

Content analysis details:   (-0.7 points, 5.0 required)

 pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
-0.7 RCVD_IN_DNSWL_LOW      RBL: Sender listed at http://www.dnswl.org/, low
                            trust
                            [209.85.128.173 listed in list.dnswl.org]
 0.0 T_MIME_NO_TEXT         No text body parts


--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="envelope"

but I am unable verify its format so that it could be inserted into our database.
Please help to decode it so that I can read the following fields in the best possible way.
1. To
2. From
3. BCC
4. Body
5. Subject
6. Attachment.

Thanks in anticipation


{"to":["pk@replydev.socialboards.com"],"from":"pragati.kumar@sdplabs.com"}
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachments"

0
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

dfdsfdsfds
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="spam_score"

-0.689
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="charsets"

{"to":"UTF-8","html":"ISO-8859-1","subject":"UTF-8","from":"UTF-8","text":"ISO-8859-1"}
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SPF"

none
--xYzZY--
```

I have to serialize this into json format.

I have tried

```
 private string RequestInputStreamToString()
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int streamLength;
        int streamRead;
        System.IO.Stream s = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
        streamLength = Convert.ToInt32(s.Length);
        Byte[] streamArray = new Byte[streamLength];
        streamRead = s.Read(streamArray, 0, streamLength);
        for (int i = 0; i < streamLength; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(streamArray[i]));
        }
       return sb.ToString();
    }
 string jsontext =RequestInputStreamToString();
 var json = JObject.Parse(jsontext);
```

But it is thronging error

```
Error reading JObject from JsonReader.
```

for more reference please check http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html 
but it is given in php and I want in C#

Comment: http://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/csharp.html

Comment: That's a lot of content for us to sift through.  Have you made any effort on this yet?  Tried something and it's not working as expected?  Show us what you've tried and explain how it's not working.  Currently this doesn't read like a question, it reads like a requirement.  Which isn't how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @paul Thanks for yours response but I have already refereed it. It has code only for sending mail but not for reading mails through send grid and I have to read mail not send Please check in my post.

Comment: @David I have tried to serialize it in json format so that it could be read. But failed.

Comment: @PragatiSingh: Show what you're trying and how it's failing.  As it stands this question is just asking us to do everything for you, which we don't generally do.

Comment: @David Please check

string jsontext =RequestInputStreamToString(); 


var json = JObject.Parse(jsontext);

Comment: @PragatiSingh: Check it for what?  Those two lines of code, devoid of any other context, look syntactically correct.  What more do you expect?  Keep in mind that I don't have your code and can't test it for you.  You have to provide information for anybody here to help you.

Comment: @David yes I know but but the comment box does not allow more that 44 characters. Then how ?

Comment: @David this is the method which is supplied there. private string RequestInputStreamToString()
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int streamLength;
        int streamRead;
        System.IO.Stream s = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
        streamLength = Convert.ToInt32(s.Length);
        Byte[] streamArray = new Byte[streamLength];
        streamRead = s.Read(streamArray, 0, streamLength);
        for (int i = 0; i < streamLength; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(streamArray[i]));
        }
       return sb.ToString();
    }

Comment: @PragatiSingh: You can edit the question.  Code shouldn't go in comments because it's difficult to read.  When asking a question, consider who might be answering it and what information would be useful to help them.  In general you want to explain what you're trying to do, show the code you're trying (narrowed down to the specifics of the question, not ALL of your code), any errors or unexpected output you're getting and where you're getting them, the inputs and runtime values which bring about the errors, and so on.  Describe the problem as succinctly as possible.

Comment: @David thanks for yours suggestions. I have edited.

Comment: @PragatiSingh: Based on the edit... What is `JObject` and what is the string that's being passed into its `Parse` method?  What does that method do?

Comment: @David **JObject is the class of Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;** and that string is that large string which i have posted above. I got that string through converting the input stream send by send grid.

Comment: @PragatiSingh: Well, according to the documentation (http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm) that method expects a JSON-formatted string.  That enormous, email-looking string in the question is not JSON, though small parts of it look like they're close to JSON.

Comment: Are you using ASP.net MWC?

Comment: @TeemuTapanila I am using asp.net with c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the hard time I find out the solution.
These are the content of multipart/form-data.
Each and every data can be read through

```
    HttpContext context;
    String to=context.Request.Params["to"];
    String from=context.Request.Params["from"];
    String html=context.Request.Params["html"];
        .......etc..............
```

After reading its content and node it can be passed to class properties and further it can be serialized into json or xml as per yours requirement.